# how to search and replace in kwrite

Tags: regex, kde-plasma

i have a txt file with a lot of lines that look like this:

item_20=_dcf718caec06464ca85dab0775681a87 Select Csr to End ALL

i want to replace everything to the right of the = character with this:

65535 _

but can't figure out how to do so.

thanks for any solutions,
babag

Comment: hmm. if i set the mode to 'regular expression' and type in =?*$ in the 'find' field, then put 65535 _ in the replace field, the 'replace', 'replace all', and 'find all' buttons gray out.

Comment: Sorry...my comment has a typo.  I have given you an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    =.*$
Replace: =65535 _
```